# PFUser losing data

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm looking into a bug on an app using the Parse iOS SDK 1.12.0. The model is "Content" with a column "author" which is a pointer to a PFUser. The query to get content includes "author" and all is well when the query returns. However after viewing the content and reloading the table (content is marked "read" by the content player) the user object no longer has data other than the objectId.

I'm wondering what might cause this or would like some way to break when the user data becomes nil again. Disabling local datastore seems to fix the problem but introduces new problems for the app. CloudCode is used to track the content views can something their trigger the app to invalidate its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the Parse SDK will update the local model at any chance it gets. One of the cloud functions had some debugging code returning users with no data accidentally left in production. I haven't dug more into the SDK but unfortunately this change isn't firing any KVO notifications so I was only able to find it by eliminating our cloud function calls.